# Can I ask questions about TempleOS and HolyC?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

The [Temple Operating System](http://www.templeos.org/) has been around in one form or another since 1993 (as TPMOS, FreeDOS, HOPPY, etc).

Without commenting on the ridiculousness of all this, would TempleOS and its language, HolyC, be on-topic for Retrocomputing?

Comment: Not an answer, but a restatement and point of dicussion — Ask yourself (and answer below), "Are these system no longer widely in practical use, but are preserved mostly in the hobby and preservationist arena for their historical and sentimental value?" Another criteria to consider is, "Are these technologies sufficiently outdated where a reasonable person would **not** consider them "contemporary" to what is modernly available?" That's what separates a system from simply being old from being truly "retro".

Comment: Umm... it's [still in development](http://www.templeos.org/Wb/Doc/ChangeLog.html#l1) -- it was just updated yesterday, so... no?

Comment: @RobertCartaino Am I right in thinking "outdated" and "historical" are the opposite of "updated yesterday"?

Comment: @cat I don't have enough context to answer that (and it's not my call). If someone came up with a patch to fix a protocol error in the PDP-11/70, that doesn't suddenly make it "contemporary".

Comment: @cat if the TI-BASIC language is updated on the latest calculator model (such as the TI-Nspire series), does that make it no longer "historical" or inappropriate for Retrocomputing?

Comment: I don't know, that was my question, which has been adequately answered

Answer (score 2):

As someone who isn't a member of this community. I think TempleOS and HolyC should not be here. They're *not* retro as they're currently maintained. They also haven't fallen into disuse as they've never been more popular than they are now.

TempleOS has made a lot of design decisions that aren't found in contemporary operating systems, for that reason it's pretty much a hobbyist thing and the author calls it a "supplementary operating system" though he aspires to one day have it reside in a spec'd out box made of stained glass.

Not to mention, it had a webstore recently. For having a future, and being actively developed it would be really confusing to have it here.

All of that said, I've asked some questions on StackOverflow about TempleOS and would love some support against their close-brigade. Let's learn about it together.

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/templeos/

Comment: TempleOS isn't maintained anymore. (author has passed away and there are no known supporters)